# Way to define a type in typescript like [one of union of interfaces] & {//atrributes}

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
// The way types defined:

interface SudoA {
    foo: string;
}

interface SudoB {
    bar: string;
}

type Sudo = SudoA | SudoB;

type SuperSudo = Sudo & {
    super: boolean;
}

const baz: SuperSudo = {

} 
// typescript (3.1.6) says i have to define both `bar` and `foo` for the object
```

What I expect is that to put `super` attribute and other attributes (coming from `Sudo` type) should be optional. The question; is this a wrong expectation? Regardless if yes or no how is this achieved?

**Edit**
Corrected the type of `baz`, my mistake :/.
What I am expecting is for `SuperSudo` defining only `super` attribute should be enough and other attributes coming from union of interfaces should be optional.

I can define a new type like
`type SuperSudo<T> = T & {}` but this ends up using `SuperSudo<T>`which I find quite verbose.

**Edit2**
Changed the title

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're saying.  `baz` is in error because it needs to have at least one of the `foo` or `bar` properties in order to be `SudoA | SudoB`.  And since `baz` is of type `Sudo` I don't understand how `SuperSudo` has anything to do with it.   Could you rephrase the question or add more examples of what you expect to work and what you expect to report an error?

Comment: When i understand your question, then you find the answer in the documentation of the release notes 2.8 typescript. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#example-6 
Here is everything covered what you need to know about typings and how to make attributes optional / readonly / modify datatypes in inheritance.

Comment: You want `SuperSudo` to only require `super` and not require *any* of the properties from `SudoA` or `SudoB`?  What if `SudoA` has two or more properties (e.g., `{foo: string, qux: number}`)?  Can a `SuperSudo` contain just one of those properties (e.g., `{super: true, foo: "a"}`)?  It's still not clear to me what you're trying to do.  *Maybe* you're looking for something like `type AllKeys<T> = T extends any ? keyof T : never; type SuperSudo = {[K in AllKeys<Sudo>]?: Extract<Sudo, Record<K, any>>[K]} & {super: boolean;}` but it's hard to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a type discriminator?

Without one, then specifying either `foo`, `bar` or both `foo` and `bar` will always satisfy the union type.

With one might look like:

```ts
interface SudoA {
  _type: "a";
  foo: string;
}

interface SudoB {
  _type: "b";
  bar: string;
}

type Sudo = SudoA | SudoB;

type SuperSudo = Sudo & {
  super: boolean;
}

const baz1_valid: SuperSudo = {
  _type: "a",
  super: true,
  foo: "bar",
}

const baz2_valid: SuperSudo = {
  _type: "b",
  super: true,
  bar: "foo",
}
```

The field name does not have to be `_type`, it simply must be the same field name with different type values on each variant.